# Bootstrap popover contents coming but not showing in html

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, coffeescript

I am having trouble in showing popover.

Scenerio:
 I want to show popover on hover, and popeover's content comes from ajax request.

Coffeescript:

```
$('.preview').bind 'mouseenter', ->
  that = @
  unless $(@).data('original-title')
    $.ajax
      type: "get"
      url: $(that).data('url')
      success: (data) ->
        $(that).data('content', data)
        $(that).popover({
          html: true
          delay: { show: 100, hide: 360000 }
          trigger: 'hover'
          content: data
          template: '<div class="popover preview-popover"><div class="arrow"></div><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content"></div></div>'
        })
```

this code generate a small popover .... which have contents(ajax loaded html) but not visible

Comment: this doesn't answer your question, but if you replace your success declartion with `success: (data) =>` you can reference `@` inside that function instead of using the `that` pattern. That is what the fat arrow is used for.

Comment: Is your `mouseenter` handler being called? Is your `$.ajax` being called? Does the `success` handler get called? Is `data` correct when it gets called? Can you provide a demo on jsfiddle.net (which supports both CoffeeScript and AJAX mocking)?

Comment: sorry for late replying but 'that' was working fine but issue was missing bootstrap-tooltip.js. i put that file in vendor and did retry it worked.